# How to put probability density function in C++?

Tags: probability, functions

I have a random variable X that has a probability density function of f(x)=x^(-1/2)/2 for all x between 0 and 1.

double RANDOM;

I need to give a value to RANDOM, that accepts the PDF

All that I know is that I can use transformation method, where

dx/dy = f(y) so x = sqrt(x), and from that y = x^2

but i don't really get, how it helps me and how can i get, that variable RANDOM is distributed like the PDF.

Thanks!

Comment: your question doesn't have latex and I can seem to parse it even if it did because it seems to not be very well written. Please write properly and take more care when writing questions. Also, coding questions are better to be asked on stack overflow. This site is more about the math rather than specific programming aspect problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you know how to generate uniform random numbers
$\displaystyle{\left\{\xi\right\}}$ in
$\displaystyle{\left[0,1\right)}$ and you want numbers distributed with $\displaystyle x^{-1/2}/2$ in $\displaystyle\left[0,1\right)$. Then
$$
\int_{0}^{x}{t^{-1/2} \over 2}\,{\rm d}t = \int_{0}^{\xi}{\rm d} t
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x = \xi^{2}.
$$
Then, generate $\displaystyle\xi$ and squared it !!!.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const double RANDMAX1=double(RAND_MAX) + 1.0;
double yourRandom();

inline double rand01()// Generate random in [0,1)
{
 return rand()/RANDMAX1;
}

int main() //Generate five of your random numbers
{
 cout<<yourRandom();
 for ( unsigned char n = 0 ; n<4 ; ++n ) cout<<",   "<<yourRandom();
 cout<<endl;
 return 0;
}

double yourRandom()
{
 static double r;
 r=rand01();
 return r*r;
}
```

Result:
$\color{#00f}{\large%
\displaystyle{\verb=6.12521e-11,   0.0173022,   0.570939,   0.21036,   0.283841=}}$

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to generate values with a distribution identical to that of a random variable $X$ is to observe that if $U\sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$ then $F_X^{-1}(U)\sim X$ (here $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$).

So if you can come up with a function representing your CDF, just apply its inverse to your usual random numbers in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer Paragraph**:  You can't define a datatype to hold real numbers on a computer.  They are not enumerable.  You can try to approximate a distribution sometimes (not always), but that still leaves you the task of quantifying how accurate your distribution is. (End disclaimer)

I'm going to assume that what you are trying to do is to generate a random value based on a PDF.  To do this, you use the CDF of the PDF.  Here is an example with finite states to explain:

> Suppose you have a 4 sided dice.  Side A has probability 10%, Side B has probability 50%, side C has probability 15%, side D has probability 25%.  Write a procedure that inputs a number U between 0 and 1 with uniform probability and outputs A,B, C, or D based on the dice probability.

To do this, we have to convert the PDF {0.1, 0.5, 0.15, 0.25} to the CDF {0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.75}.  Using the CDF we create the necessary ranges:

```
 f(U) {
   if (0 < U < 0.1) return A
   if (0.1 < U < 0.6) return B
   if (0.6 < U < 0.75) return C 
   if (0.75 < U < 1) return D 
 }
```

We do the same thing for nondiscrete states:

$$PDF = \frac 12 x^2 \text{ for } 0 \le x \le 1$$
so
$$CDF = \int_{0}^{x}\frac 12 x^2 dx = x^2 \text { for } 0 \le x \le 1$$

Notice that the CDF takes on values between 0 and 1.  You want to write a function that returns the x value for which the CDF is equal to U (your value produced by a uniform distribution):

$$\{x \mid CDF = U\}$$
$$\{x \mid x^2 = U\}$$
$$\{\sqrt{U}\}$$

```
f(U) {
  return sqrt(U)
}
```

Now use your C++ libraries to generate the $U$ value with uniform distribution between 0 and 1 (ask on stackoverflow if you don't know how to do that, it is off topic for this site) and f(U) will generate a value with the desired distribution.